# Nth 1 in a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

A array of length `t` has all elements initialized by 1 .Now we can perform two types of queries on the array

1. to replace the element at `i`th index to 0 .This query is denoted by 0 index
2. find and print an integer denoting the index of the kth `1` in array A on a new line; if no such index exists print `-1`.This query is denoted by 1 k

Now suppose for array of length `t=4` all its elements at the beginning are `[1,1,1,1]` now for query `0 2` the array becomes `[1,0,1,1]` and for query `1 3` the output comes out to be `4`

I have used a brute force approach but how to make the code more efficient?

```
n,q=4,2
arr=[1]*4
for i in range(q):
    a,b=map(int,input().split())
    if a==0:
        arr[b-1]=0
    else:
        flag=True
        count=0
        target=b
        for i,j in enumerate(arr):
            if j ==1:
                count+=1
                if count==target:
                    print(i+1)
                    flag=False
                    break
        if flag:
            print(-1)
```

I have also tried to first append all the indexes of 1 in a list and then do binary search but pop 0 changes the indices due to which the code fails

```
def binary_search(low,high,b):
    while(low<=high):
        mid=((high+low)//2)
        #print(mid)
        if mid+1==b:
           print(stack[mid]+1)
           return
        elif mid+1>b:
            high=mid-1
        else:
            low=mid+1


n=int(input())
q=int(input())
stack=list(range(n))
for i in range(q):
    a,b=map(int,input().split())
    if a==0:
        stack.pop(b-1)
        print(stack)

    else:
        if len(stack)<b:
            print(-1)
            continue
        else:
            low=0
            high=len(stack)-1
            binary_search(low,high,b)
```

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for the input .Will keep that in mind :)

Comment: This is somewhat similar to a recent question, which I can't find. You can maintain a second list which has indexes of each 1. This makes  the read-only type-1 queries O(1), but the type-0 queries become O(t) worst case, but only up to t times, so their amortized time does not grow with more queries.

Comment: Binary search requires a sorted list, which you do not have. On a pure functional approach, it is impossible to do better than O(t). Only by doing the work to maintain an index can you make some calls faster (which are likely to be the majority of the work). On the other hand, if t <<< n, where n is the number of queries, you shouldn't care about that.

Comment: @KennyOstrom can you please explain with the help of an example?

Comment: I can post an answer if you clarify some things. If the array is length t, and the number of queries is n, which dominates?

Comment: @KennyOstrom I have used binary search for sorted indices that contains 1. However that will not work because of the updates of 1 to 0,there will be a need to pop indices that have changed to zero .

Comment: @KennyOstrom both t and n are the same as far as constraints are concerned.

Comment: I'm just curious: Is this a programming challenge on hackerrank?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/modena-coding-oct-2017/challenges/kthzero/copy-from/1304944828

Comment: @MSeifert This is quite similar but i found this question on leetcode.

Comment: Domain specific knowledge might do better if some special cases apply (e.g. all type-0 queries happen before all type-1 queries), but without a special case, the segment tree answer is general purpose and a huge improvement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a binary tree where each node gives you the number of ones that are below and at the left of it. So if *n* is 7, that tree would initially look like this (the actual list with all ones is shown below it):

```
         4
      /    \
    2        2
   / \      / \
  1   1    1   1
 ----------------
 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 -
```

Setting the array element at index 4 (zero-based) to 0, would change that tree to:

```
         4
      /    \
    2        1*
   / \      / \
  1   1    0*  1
 ----------------
 1 1 1 1  0*1 1 -
```

Putting a 0 thus represents a *O(log(n))* time complexity.

Counting the number of ones can then also be done in the same time complexity by summing up the node values while descending down the tree in the right direction.

Here is Python code you could use. It represents the tree in a [list in breadth-first order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays). I have not gone to great lengths to further optimise the code, but it has the above time complexities:

```
class Ones:
    def __init__(self, n): # O(n)
        self.lst = [1] * n
        self.one_count = n
        self.tree = []
        self.size = 1 << (n-1).bit_length()
        at_left = self.size // 2
        width = 1
        while width <= at_left:
            self.tree.extend([at_left//width] * width)
            width *= 2

    def clear_index(self, i): # O(logn)
        if i >= len(self.lst) or self.lst[i] == 0:
            return
        self.one_count -= 1
        self.lst[i] = 0        
        # Update tree 
        j = 0
        bit = self.size >> 1
        while bit >= 1:
            go_right = (i & bit) > 0
            if not go_right:
                self.tree[j] -= 1
            j = j*2 + 1 + go_right
            bit >>= 1

    def get_index_of_ith_one(self, num_ones): # O(logn)
        if num_ones <= 0 or num_ones > self.one_count:
            return -1
        j = 0
        k = 0
        bit = self.size >> 1
        while bit >= 1:
            go_right = num_ones > self.tree[j]
            if go_right:
                k |= bit
                num_ones -= self.tree[j]
            j = j*2 + 1 + go_right
            bit >>= 1
        return k

    def is_consistent(self): # Only for debugging
        # Check that list can be derived by calling get_index_of_ith_one for all i 
        lst = [0] * len(self.lst)
        for i in range(1, self.one_count+1):
            lst[self.get_index_of_ith_one(i)] = 1
        return lst == self.lst

# Example use
ones = Ones(12)
print('tree', ones.tree)
ones.clear_index(5)
ones.clear_index(2)
ones.clear_index(1)
ones.clear_index(10)
print('tree', ones.tree)
print('lst', ones.lst)
print('consistent = ', ones.is_consistent())
```

Be aware that this treats indexes as zero-based, while the method `get_index_of_ith_one` expects an argument that is at least 1 (but it returns a zero-based index).

It should be easy to adapt to your needs.

#### Complexity

- Creation: O(n)
- Clear at index: O(logn)
- Get index of one: O(logn)
- Space complexity: O(n)

Comment: Perhaps your binary tree is wrong but the approach is perfect.

Comment: sorry,my bad the binary tree you made is for the example which I gave but could you explain what 1 1 1 1  1 1 1 - below your B Tree diagram depicts?

Comment: It is the actual array. The hyphen at the end is to indicate that the list does not go that far. You'll see in the code I have `self.tree` and `self.lst`. The binary tree is the first, the actual list the second. For not making the code more complex I decided to make the tree as big as needed to host a list that has 2^k elements, even though the actual list might be shorter.

Comment: https://ideone.com/xFrsfG I have used segment tree for this but from line no 38-45 during recursion the value of left right overrides. Trincot could you please have a look?

Comment: I suggest you post this problem as a new question, so more people can look at it. Make sure to specify exactly what you get and how that differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some general tricks:

- Check if the n-th element is too big for the list before iterating. If you also keep a "counter" that stores the number of zeros, you could even check if `nth >= len(the_list) - number_of_zeros` (not sure if `>=` is correct here, it seems like the example uses 1-based indices so I could be off-by-one). That way you save time whenever too big values are used.
- Use more efficient functions.

  So instead of `input` you could use `sys.stdin.readline` (note that it will include the trailing newline).

  And, even though it's probably not useful in this context, the built-in [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module would be better than the `binary_search` function you created.

  You could also use `for _ in itertools.repeat(None, q)` instead of `for i in range(q)`, that's a bit faster and you don't need that index.

Then you can use some more specialized facts about the problem to improve the code:

- You only store zeros and ones, so you can use `if j` to check for ones and `if not j` to check for zeros. These will be a *bit faster* than manual comparisons especially in when you do that in a loop.
- Every time you look for the nth 1, you could create a temporary dictionary (or a list) that contains the encountered `n`s + index. Then re-use that dict for subsequent queries (dict-lookup and list-random-access is `O(1)` while your search is `O(n)`). You could even expand it if you have subsequent queries without change in-between.

  However if a change happens you either need to discard that dictionary (or list) or update it.

A few nitpicks:

- The variable names are not very descriptive, you could use `for index, item in enumerate(arr):` instead of `i` and `j`.
- You use a list, so `arr` is a misleading variable name.
- You have two `i` variables.

---

But don't get me wrong. It's a very good attempt and the fact that you use `enumerate` instead of a `range` is great and shows that you already write pythonic code.

Answer (score 2):

Consider something akin to the interval tree:

- root node covers the entire array
- children nodes cover left and right halves of the parent range respectively
- each node holds the number of ones in its range

Both replace and search queries could be completed in logarithmic time.

Comment: Yeah. This is the job for a [Fenwick Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or a segment tree -- just not the Wikipedia one, you can rather read [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/segment-trees/tutorial/) or [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-set-1-sum-of-given-range/).

Comment: I initially though of segment tree but then to store index would be a problem.

Comment: Yes, but it's an O(log) problem. Having two O(log) is way better than having O(1) + O(n), unless for some reason n were not the dominant term.

Comment: Is there cost associated with creating a tree structure or can it be implemented on the list/array itself?

Comment: This is a separate structure. Everything has cost. Time was addressed in the answer. Looks like space gets a constant factor.

Answer (score 0):

Refactored with less lines, so more efficient in terms of line count but run time probably the same O(n).

```
n,q=4,2
arr=[1]*4
for i in range(q):
    query, target = map(int,input('query target: ').split())
    if query == 0:
        arr[target-1] = 0
    else:
        count=0
        items = enumerate(arr, 1)
        try:
            while count < target:
                index, item = next(items)
                count += item
        except StopIteration as e:
            index = -1
        print(index)
```

Assumes `arr` contains ONLY ones and zeroes - you don't have to check if an item is one before you add it to count, adding zero has no affect.

No *flags* to check, just keep calling next on the enumerate object (`items`) till you reach your target or the end of `arr`.

---

For runtime efficiency, using an *external* library but basically the same process (algorithm):

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(q):
    query, target = map(int,input('query target: ').split())
    if query == 0:
        arr[target-1] = 0
    else:
        index = -1
        a = np.array(arr).cumsum() == target
        if np.any(a):
            index = np.argmax(a) + 1
        print(index)
```